# How to get numbers from a character array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops, character

I'm working on a project for my class and have come upon a roadblock. Let's say I have a space separated character array (string) that contains numbers (each followed by a space character). Assume it looks something like this:

`0 1 15 10 6 2`

The number of items in it will never be constant so I cannot use `sscaf()` to get all the numbers. I tried looping trough it as characters but I ended up separating the double digit numbers messing things up.

Can someone guide me on how I can get each number in the string and save it to a int array without separating the double digit ones? I'm writing this in C

Thanks in advance

Comment: You'd need two pointers, a head and a tail. Move the tail until you hit an empty space, then subtract the tail from the head and allocate a new char * then add all the characters from head to tail into the new char * - do this until tail is at the end of the string

Comment: You can loop over an unkown number of numbers with the help of `sscanf()`s return value. Just don't follow the common malpractice to ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

> how I can get each number in the string and save it to a `int` array without separating the double digit ones?

1. Scan the *string* once to find the number of `int`
2. Define the array
3. Scan again and save into the array

...

```
const char *s = "0 1 15 10 6 2 ";
int count = scans_ints(s, NULL);
if (count <= 0) Handle_Bad_intput();
else {
  int arr[count];
  sscan_ints(s, arr);
}
```

---

Possible `sscan_ints()`  (untested)

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>

int sscan_ints(const char *s, int *arr) {
  int count = 0;
  for (;;) {
    // Consume leading spaces: ease detection of end-of-line
    while (isspace((unsigned char) *s)) s++;
    if (*s == '\0') break;
    char *endptr;  // Location where conversion ended
    errno = 0;
    long num = strtol(s, &endptr, 10);
    if (s == endptr) return -1;  // non-numeric text
    if (errno || num < INT_MIN || num > INT_MAX) return -1; // number too big
    if (arr) {
      arr[count] = (int) num;
    }
    count++;
    s = endptr;
  }
  return count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to your problem would be to navigate through the string and add the characters into a buffer until you hit an empty space, then have a function that takes that buffer and converts it into a number.

But before that we have to count the number of empty spaces, since that will tell us the number of integers we have, or you could have a default value for the array of integers and realloc when there are more numbers than the default value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define WHITE_SPACE (0x20)


int32_t
get_len_numbers(const char *str) {

    int32_t     n;
    const char *ptr;

    ptr = str;
    n   = 0;

    for(; *ptr != 0; ++ptr)
        n += (*ptr == ' ');

    return(n + 1);

}

int32_t
stoi(const char *number) {

    int32_t n;

    n = 0;

    for(; *number != 0; ++number)
        n = (n * 10) + (*number & 0x0F);

    return(n);

}


int main(void) {

    int32_t           len;
    register int32_t  i;
    register int32_t  j;

    uint8_t           buf[32];
    char              *str;

    int32_t           *numbers;

    str     = "1 5 25 30 99";

    len     = get_len_numbers(str);
    numbers = malloc(sizeof(int) * len);

    if(numbers == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    for(i = 0, j = 0; ; ++str) {

        if(*str == WHITE_SPACE || *str == 0) {

            buf[i] = 0;

            numbers[j++] = stoi(&buf[0]);

            i = 0;

            if(*str == 0)
                break;

        } else {

            buf[i++] = *str;

        }


    }

    return(0);
}
```